# getting the textbox input from javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery $.get function to get the data and for each data, I am making a textbox for the user to enter corresponding text.

```
for(var i = 0; i <data.length; i++){

                var newHtml = '<tr><td>'+ idx + '</td><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].type + '</td><td>'
                + data[i].required + '</td><td>'+ '<input type="text" id="mValue'+i+'" class="form-control" placeholder="enter number'+i+'" /></td></tr>'; 
                $(newHtml).appendTo('#dt_basic');
                idx++;

                _currentValues[data[i].name] = $('#mValue');
            }
```

as shown in the code, I made a `</input>` with id of "mValuei" and `i` could be from 0 to the data.length. How do i get the value of the input box? I tried `$('#mValue'+i).val()` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where is the code where you are getting the value? Please include the `$.get` function code as well.

Comment: What is `_currentValues` ?

Comment: uhm... $('#mValue' + i) has no value, isn't it? If you write some text or set text on $('#mValue' + i), you can get value with $('#mValue'+i).val() or $(".form-control").eq(i).val()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value` attribute to fill `input`

```
 '<input type="text" id="mValue'+i+'" class="form-control" placeholder="enter number'+i+'"  value="'+i+'"/>'
```

## In jquery :

### 1. Setter :

```
  $('#mValue'+i).val('new value of input') ;
```

### 2. Getter :

```
  currentVal=$('#mValue'+i).val() ;
```

---

Thus, you use `val` as getter  (`val()` without argument), however, you should use it as setter (with one argument which is the new value of INPUT)

---

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/qjs7hj2r/1/)

## [Elegant Code](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/qjs7hj2r/2/)

```
$(data.map((e,i)=>
       `<tr>
            <td>${i}</td>
            <td>${e.name}</td>
            <td>${e.type}</td>
            <td>${e.required}</td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="enter number${i}" class="form-control" id="mValue${i}" value="${e.name}"></td></tr>`).join('')).appendTo('#dt_basic');
```

Comment: if I try `currentVal = currentVal + $('#mValue' + i).val(); console.log(currentVal)` I get `[object Object]` in my console

Comment: am I doing something wrong? my `currentVal` is set `var currentVal = {}`

Comment: Enjoy Elegant Code here= > Just ONE line :https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/qjs7hj2r/2/ . .. hhh :)